# What does it mean for a relative homology group to be free of rank?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

What does it mean for the relative homology group $\tilde{H}_{i}((\Delta^{n})^{k})$ to be free of rank $\begin{pmatrix}n\\k+1\end{pmatrix}$? 
And what does this mean the actual relative homology is?

Comment: The simplex $\Delta^n$ is contractible.  So, its homology groups should be $0$.  When you are doing relative homology groups, you usually have some subspace in mind.

Comment: I'm really sorry I had meant reduced homology...

Comment: Even so, the product of contractible spaces is contractible.  And the reduced homology is the same as the unreduced for every $i$ but $i=0$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 The OP is using $(\Delta^n)^k$ to denote the $k$ skeleton of the $n$-simplex. So for instance the $1$-skeleton of the $2$-simplex $(\Delta^2)^1$ is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$.

Comment: @DanielRust Thank you.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

A free abelian group of finite rank $n$ is isomorphic to the group $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: So does that mean the relative homology group in this case would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{\begin{pmatrix}n\\k+1\end{pmatrix}}$?

Comment: Yep, if you're working with usual singular homology with coefficients in the integers.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the relative homology of the $k-$skeleton of the $m-$simplex would it thus still be the case?

Comment: Do you mean the relative homology of the $m$-simplex relative to the $k$-skeleton? We usually reserve the notation $\tilde{H}_i(X)$ to mean the $i$th reduced homology of $X$, as opposed to relative homology which is written as $H_i(X,A)$ where we mean the $i$th homology of $X$ relative to $A$.

Comment: Ahh so sorry I mean reduced homology...

Comment: You would think that $i$ plays a part in the homology...